# Confusion of forces for the experiment in Pascal's Principle

Tags: forces, pressure, work, fluid-statics

The problem is that I simply can't understand why there is even an extra force on one side if the force on the other side is way less.

How can an object of less weight balance an object of weight that is greater than that just because it is placed on pistons that is filled with some fluid underneath it? From where does the extra force arise from?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your last point is kind of an interesting remark, I would guess that you're alluding to Newton's Third Law or some variant. As @trula mentions, it's easier to consider a lever. Then, the "extra force" needed to keep the lever still is the normal force at the fulcrum, and the reaction force on your hand is a result of the normal force of the lever supporting the weight. Likewise, the bottom of your container will experience an increased normal force, and the reaction force is a result of the normal force of the piston supporting the weight.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you so concerned with a small force holding a large one in equilibrium. The same happens on a lever long side small force, short side large force, or a pulley , with many rolls. The important thing is, to move the large force a small distance, the small force has to move a large distance , so $F_1*s_1=F_2*s_2$ The explanation in fluid uses, that fluids have the same external pressure independent of the area.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i too thought about the fact that 'work in' equals the 'work out' and also the concept of "action of small force over large distance to equal the the action of large force over small distance" but i simply can't comprehend the concept of "small force balancing large force" it feels really weird.